# $L^1$ random variable property

Tags: random-variables, conditional-expectation

If $X\in L^1$ is a random variable, then
$$\forall\epsilon>0:\exists\delta>0:\forall \operatorname{event}A:\left(P(A)\leq\delta\Rightarrow\mathbb{E}(|X| 1_A)\leq\epsilon\right)\,.$$

Could anybody give me a hint as to how to (dis)prove this?

Comment: Note: it is not equivalent, because the original statements means uniform convergence (i.e. the convergence rate is independent of $A$)

Comment: @supinf, O thank you I see, do you know whether it can be true if I move the $\forall \operatorname{event}A$ before the $\exists\delta>0$? I edited the question

Comment: If $X$ is bounded then the claim is obvious. Then note that since $X \in L^1$, for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a bounded random variable $Y$ so that $\mathbb{E}(\vert X - Y \vert) < \epsilon$.

Comment: Even simpler: choose $\delta=P(A)/2$ and the claim holds always.

Comment: For $X\equiv 1$, $\mathbb{E}(|X|\mid A) = \frac{\mathbb P(A)}{\mathbb P(A)}=1$.

Comment: Please replace every $$\mathbb{E}(|X|\mid 1_A)$$ by $$\mathbb{E}(|X|;A)=\mathbb{E}(|X|1_A)$$

Comment: The first implication is wrong as well... Note that $$\forall\epsilon>0:\forall \operatorname{event}A:\exists\delta>0:0<P(A)\leq\delta\Rightarrow\left(0=1\
 \text{ and I am the King of England}\right).$$

Comment: @Did, that depends on whether there are arbitrarily small events $A$. I removed the first implication.

Comment: @Carucel Actually, no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition of the Lebesgue integral, for any positive $\varepsilon$, there exists $Y$ such that

1. $0\leqslant Y\leqslant \left|X\right|$,
2. there exist an integer $N$, constants $a_1,\dots,a_N$ and measurable sets $B_1,\dots,B_N$ such that $Y=\sum_{i=1}^Na_i\mathbf 1_{B_i}$, where $\mathbf 1$ denotes the indicator function of a set,
3. $\mathbb E\left|X\right|-\mathbb E\left[Y\right]\lt \varepsilon/2$.

With this in mind, note that 
$$\tag{*}  \mathbb E\left[|X|\mathbf 1_A\right]=\mathbb E\left[\left(|X|-Y\right)\mathbf 1_A\right]+\mathbb E\left[Y\mathbf 1_A\right]$$
and by 1., the first term of the right hand side does not exceed $\mathbb E\left[ |X|-Y \right]$ which can be in turn bounded by $\varepsilon/2$, by 3. The second term of the right hand side of (*) is smaller that $M\mathbb P\left(A\right)$, where $M=\max_{1\leqslant i\leqslant n}a_i$. In conclusion, we are sure that *for any measurable set* $A$, 
$$\mathbb E\left[|X|\mathbf 1_A\right]\leqslant \varepsilon/2+M\mathbb P\left(A\right).$$
Do you see which choice of $\delta$ will work?

Comment: $\delta=\epsilon/(2 M)$ is ok, right? Thank you very much for your explanation!

Comment: Yes, it is. ${}{} $